# Tobit (Censored or truncated) model

Tags: r

i'm working on Tobit modele where my dependent var is "rate of credit default" with many zeros and my explanatory variables are timeseries data: PIB, Saving and Inflation with their lags (1 to 2 lags per vars) and differences(differences for every lagged vars for avoiding non-stationary vars). My data go from 1990 to 2020 = 31 observations (small length, i know!).

I used "censReg package" to predict "rate of credit default" but when trying to run my code (see: "My rcode"), it doesn't work and everytime R return me a message (see: "Messages returned by R)!

I'm not a expert R user and i need someone's help who knows tobits models and packages to resolve my probleme

Dependent var = "TDGSovereign" : 28 values of 0 (left censored) and 3 values !=0 (uncensored)
Thanks

```r
attach(Data1)

Tobitsouverain <- censReg::censReg(formula = TDGSovereign ~ pib1diff + pib1 + pib2 +
                                     pib2diff + pib3 + pib3diff + eprg1 + eprg1diff +
                                     eprg2 + eprg2diff + eprg3 + eprg3diff + inf1 +
                                     inf1diff + inf2 + inf2diff + inf3 + inf3diff,
                                   left = 0, right = 1, logLikOnly = FALSE, data = Data1) 

stepAIC(Tobitsouverain, direction = "both") # to remove non-significative variable (p-value>10%)
summary(margEff(Tobitsouverain)) # to get marginal effect of explanatory var
```

Messages returned by R:

```r
> Tobitsouverain <- censReg::censReg(formula = TDGSovereign ~ pib1diff + pib1 + pib2 +
+                                      pib2diff + pib3 + pib3diff + eprg1 + eprg1diff +
+                                      eprg2 + eprg2diff + eprg3 + eprg3diff + inf1 +
+                                      inf1diff + inf2 + inf2diff + inf3 + inf3diff,
+                                    left = 0, right = 1, logLikOnly = FALSE, data = Data1) 
> stepAIC(Tobitsouverain, direction = "both")
Error in nObs.maxLik(fit) : 
  cannot return the number of observations: please re-run 'maxLik' and provide a gradient function using argument 'grad' or (if no gradient function is specified) a log-likelihood function using argument 'logLik' that return the gradients or log-likelihood values, respectively, at each observation
> summary(margEff(Tobitsouverain))
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': the model must contain either coefficient 'logSigma' or both coefficients 'logSigmaMu' and 'logSigmaNu'
```